# Newtonsoft JSON Schema - $ref is resolved, ignoring required though

Tags: json, json.net, schema

I externalized a portion of my json schema into a separate schema file.
For example: `"$ref": "http://schema.company.com/boroughschema.json"`
Within this schema I specify required properties, when validating a known bad json file, it doesn't complain that a required property is missing.

```
"required": [
        "Name",
        "Representative",
        "District"
]
```

I purposely leave off "District" in the source json, and there are no complaints when validating.

Using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema 3.0.11.
The original schema validates just fine, if I move the schema portion to a definitions that works as well.

```
private bool ValidateViaExternalReferences(string jsonstring)
{
    JSchemaPreloadedResolver resolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver();

    // load schema
    var schemaText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(COMPLEXSCHEMAFILE);

    // Rather than rely on 100% http access, use a resolver and
    // preload schema with http://schema.company.com/boroughschema.json
    var schemaTextBorough = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(BOROUGHSCHEMAFILE);
    resolver.Add(new Uri("http://schema.company.com/boroughschema.json"), schemaTextBorough);

    JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaText, resolver);
    JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonstring);

    // validate json
    IList<ValidationError> errors;
    bool valid = json.IsValid(schema, out errors);
    if (!valid)
    {
    foreach (var validationerr in errors)
    {
        Append2Log(validationerr.ToString());
    }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Missing "District" yields no errors, I expect the same correct behavior when using the original schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had placed the:
 "required": [
    "Name",
    "Representative",
    "District"
  ] fragment in the wrong place.

I apologize, it behaves as expected.